# If Result of For Loop is Equivalent Python

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, equivalent

I have a for loop which is pulling AWS snapshots, which then puts the snapshot in a `dict`.

`for snapshot in current_snapshots:
   dict1 = {snapshotYear:{snapshotMonth:{snapshotDay:[[snapshot]]}}}
   print dict1`

This correctly prints out

`{"2014": {"7": {"22": [["Snapshot:snap-XXXXXXXX"]]}}}
{"2014": {"7": {"22": [["Snapshot:snap-YYYYYYYY"]]}}}`

I want to be able to say that if the `snapshotDay` is the same, it should print out

`{"2014": {"7": {"22": [["Snapshot:snap-XXXXXXXX"], ["Snapshot:snap-YYYYYYYY"]]}}}`, and if it's the same `snapshotMonth`

print out

`{"2014": {"7": {"22": [["Snapshot:snap-XXXXXXXX"]}, {"15": [["Snapshot:snap-YYYYYY"]]}}}`

This requires setting the result of the for loop equivalent. I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

Comment: So to access a snapshot you need to say `dict1["2014"]["7"]["22"][0]`. Ouch. Why not concatenate the strings for dates, so you'll just have to do `dict1["2014722"][0]`?

Comment: Correct -- I do this because is works well with JSON.

Comment: @user3822146, Josh's suggestion does not impact its ability to be json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict
defaultdict_dict=lambda :defaultdict(defaultdict_dict)
data = defaultdict(defaultdict_dict)

for snapshot in current_snapshots:
   try:
      data[snapshotYear][snapshotMonth][snapshotDay].append(snapshot)
   except AttributeError:
      data[snapshotYear][snapshotMonth][snapshotDay] = [snapshot]

print json.dumps(data)
```

is probably how I would handle it ...

Comment: you do know that python has a json library that dumps json for you for any serializable object ... anyway there you go its now json